# The wife of Zevulun (Sefer HaYashar)

Tags: names, midrash

Sefer HaYashar to VaYeishev says that Zevulun went towards Midian and married Merishah daughter Molad son of Abida son of Midian and brought her to Canaan where she begot Sered, Elon and Yachleel.
Back in Chayei Sarah, Sefer HaYashar names the sons of Midian: Epha, Epher, Chanoch, Abida and Elda'ah and then lists all of their sons. It says that Chur, Molar, Kerury and Molchi were the sons of Abida.

Why is Molad not mentioned there, surely he is the most relevant of Abida's sons since his son-in-law was Zevulun?

Comment: What version of Sefer Hayashar are you using? This one? http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&st=&pgnum=90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is merely a transfer of the letters in Hebrew. In Chayei Sarah his name is *M'lud* (מלוד). In VaYeishev his name is written *Molad* (מולד).

Although there is nothing in this source to indicate why the change of letter arrangement, just considering the meaning of the words could be an indication.

M'lod means literally *From Lud*. [Lud is a city-state in Asia Minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydia) which is mentioned in [Pesachim 50a in connection with the concept of Mesirut Nefesh.](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Talmud/pesach3.html#fn_42) It would be in what is modern day Turkey. At the end of parshat Chayei Sarah in Sefer HaYashar it indicates that the children of Avraham and Keturah moved to Asia Minor. In particular, sacrificing ones life at the hands of the government for the preservation of the community as a whole, as described there, is a highly meritorious act.

Molad has several meanings such as *new moon* and *hard labor*. But in this context, it also has a plain meaning of *descendent*. His merit derives from Avraham and his second wife, Keturah.

There may be mention in another midrashic source about the particular meritorious act of the father of Merusha that accounted for his name change.

Comment: A city in east Asia from the Talmud??? How about a city in Israel (Chr 1:8:12), or better yet a son of Shem son of Noach (Gen 10:22), or even a city in the middle east (Eze 30:5, Isa 66:19)!

Comment: I think the fact that Keturah's descendants settled in the Lud in the Middle East seems to agree with the common tradition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keturah#Descendants Also, see this Chabad article: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/698144/jewish/What-happened-to-Abrahams-other-descendants.htm