# Ancient DNA - Jews and Canaanites

Tags: canaan, israel

A study in 2020 made the claim, using aDNA (Ancient DNA) recovered from Canaanite bodies that the modern Jews are descended from the Canaanites. This seems to lend credence to the claims against an Exodus and the alleged origin of the Jews as a population diverging from the Canaanites in religious practice (monolatry/monotheism)

https://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(20)30487-6

How can one reconcile this with the Biblical narrative?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm not an expert, but I gather from the summary that the research's conclusion is that modern Levantine-associated groups such as Jews and Arabs share 50% or more (but not 100%) of their DNA with ancient Levantine groups, and are descendants of people related to the individuals used for the study. That is not quite the same as saying that Jews are descendants of Canaanites. Indeed, according to Jewish scripture and traditions, the ancestors of the Jews originated in the Levant before coming to Egypt.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78862/canaanite-wives-of-the-bnei-yaakov-sefer-hayashar

Comment: We also have to ask how these researchers know that those bodies are of Canaanites. Maybe instead they're of ancient Israelites?

Comment: @Meir I haven't looked at this study in particular. But I've read in other studies they made assumptions as to what settlements had a Jewish vs Non Jewish population based on fecal matter that shows diet, or by whether they had non kosher animal piles showing the populace ate non kosher meat. Unfortunately this method doesn't distinguish between Jewish settlements who just didn't keep kosher. Or Jewish vs Samaritan settlements as they would have similar diets.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a scientist, so someone please correct me if any of this is implausible on scientific grounds.

Abraham Isaac and Jacob are three generations in Canaan, leading to the 13 children of Jacob. Who did these 13 children marry and have children with before coming down to Egypt as a group of 70 people? Presumably there was some admixture with the local inhabitants of Canaan before the descent to Egypt. This could account for an infusion of genetics from the Canaanitic population into the Israelite population from its very inception.

Furthermore, this study compares the genetics of modern Jews, i.e. descendants of Israelites that (traditionally understood) re-entered the Land of Israel (Canaan) and in so doing were not always perfect faithful adherents of the Torah. Many improperly took gentile (Canaanite) wives, and adopted Canaanite practices, etc. Others may have married converts of Canaanite origin. All this would explain, again how another infusion of genetics from Canaanites would have entered into the Israelite nation.

So when comparing the genetics of modern Jews to that of pre-Israelite Canaanites, it wouldn't be altogether surprising, from a traditional perspective, that there are shared genetics.